# How to remove or hide default property from json output which using default library of asp.net

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, properties, exceptionhandler

I've got code on fist screenshot [first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxdp1.jpg), needed to display only this four properties. But when i start using this code i get my 4 properties + 2 unnecessary. Second screenshot(result):[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mzQY.jpg)

I tried to this one, but its not working[full code with an attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E3d8.png)

Comment: I don't need to show "Instance" and "Extentions"

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Code is text - post it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an anonymous type instead of ProblemDetails

```
var json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject ( new 
                                  {
                                    Status=....
                                   });
```